# Thunderbird Quick Filter - remove default text

Tags: thunderbird

The Quick Filter window displays by default the text `Filter These messages... <Ctrl+Shift+K>` as displayed on the attached screenshot.

[image]

The text disappears when I start typing into the window, but reappears again when the text in the window is deleted.

I find the text distracting. Is there any way to remove it? I would like to have an empty window with no text.

I am using Thunderbird 24.4.0

Comment: Just keeping things connected, the OP asked this Q on mozillazine as well: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=39&t=2824577

Comment: @slm - I have not received any reaction on mozillazine for one week, so I have posted the same question here, and added a bounty.

Comment: Yeah I noticed, I was  putting the link here just in case someone else ever googles either of these things they'll stumble into the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way to remove it.

I quickly hacked together a [simple addon](http://ha.cker.li/stuff/emptyqftf.xpi) that does this via an [XUL Overlay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XUL/Overlays) specified in its [chrome.manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#overlay). I don't see a good way to achieve this without an addon or modifying files.

**Technical details:**

The original file, `chrome/messenger/content/messenger/quickFilterBar.xul` located inside `omni.ja` sets the text with the following XUL tag using the attribute `emptytextbase` (on line 139, for Thunderbird 24.5.0):

```
<textbox id="qfb-qs-textbox" flex="1"
         type="search"
         placeholder=""
         emptytextbase="&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.base;"
         ...
```

Just for reference: `&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.base;` is defined in `chrome/<lang>/locale/<lang>/messenger/quickFilterBar.dtd`, also located inside `omni.ja`.

The XUL Overlay inside my addon changes the text to an empty string with the following line:

```
<textbox id="qfb-qs-textbox" emptytextbase=""></textbox>
```

Comment: so what do I need to change and where? I see a file `/usr/share/icedove/omni.ja` but it looks like a binary file. Is there any way to do it without installing your addon?

Comment: You need to unpack the omni.ja using a zip decompressing utility (`unzip` works, 7-Zip fails). Then you can modify `chrome/messenger/content/messenger/quickFilterBar.xul`, changing line 139 from `emptytextbase="&quickFilterBar.textbox.emptyText.base;"` to `emptytextbase=""`, and last re-pack the omni.ja with `zip -qr9XD omni.ja *`. One other way to do this without using _my_ addon is to look at my addon and create your own. Please note though, that if you don't use an addon but modify the `omni.ja` you will have to repeat this procedure every time you update Thunderbird.

Comment: thanks a lot for the instructions. Modifying `chrome/messenger/content/messenger/quickFilterBar.xul` as described by you did not have any effect. But I have solved the problem by editing `chrome/en-US/locale/en-US/messenger/quickFilterBar.dtd` and setting `<!ENTITY quickFilterBar.show.key2 "">` and `<!ENTITY quickFilterBar.show.key2 "">`.